# Codeigniter - Set_value on checkbox's checked status

Tags: forms, codeigniter, set, checkbox

I use the form validation libraray for a form in Codeigniter. When I use the set_value on the input fields for repopulating it works great, but how do I do this on the checkboxes? If they're checked I want them to still be checked if the form errors return true.

How?

This doesn't work:

```
        <?php
        $js = 'onClick="shipping(this.form)"';
        echo form_checkbox('fillShipping', 'check', set_value('fillShipping'), $js); 
        ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your view, try using something like this:

```
<?php 
$js = 'onClick="shipping(this.form)"';
echo form_checkbox('fillShipping','check', set_checkbox('fillShipping','check'), $js);?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a dedicated function for that.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck" value="1" <?php echo set_checkbox('mycheck', '1'); ?> />
```